# Was Harold Saxon the next Prime Minister after Harriet Jones?

Tags: doctor-who, timeline

So did the Doctor start the events leading to his capture by the Master, and the events of The Sound of Drums/Last of the Time Lords, when he caused Harriet Jones's resignation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Harriet Jones](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Harriet_Jones) was Prime Minister between 2006 and 2008.
- [Harold Saxon](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Master_%28Harold_Saxon%29) was Prime Minister in 2008.

According to the [Harriet Jones](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Harriet_Jones) page:

> Furious with Jones, the Doctor told her he could bring her down with
>   just six words. When she stood by her actions, he whispered those six
>   words to her aide: "Don't you think she looks tired?" Soon she was
>   fending off rumours of ill-health and facing a vote of no confidence
>   (TV: The Christmas Invasion). Her government was damaged and **she lost
>   power to Harold Saxon in the 2008 election**, as she was indicated as
>   being PM on Saxon's campaign website.

I haven't been able to find the campaign website, with it being a "viral" site it doesn't seem to be online any longer.

**So did the Doctor start the events leading to his capture by the Master, and the events of The Sound of Drums/Last of the Time Lords, when he caused Harriet Jones's resignation?**

He certainly helped. We know from *Love & Monsters* (series 2, episode 10), that he was back before that happened and in politics (the article visible has Saxon leading the polls), so could have ascended to power anyway.

Comment: I had a look at the archived version of Saxon's website and [the only reference to Harriet Jones I found](http://web.archive.org/web/20100612202153/http://www.haroldsaxon.co.uk/mybeliefs2.shtml) was: “One of my predecessors, Harriet Jones, was the latest to make the mistake of concealing Britain's encounters with alien life.”

Comment: I seem to recall there were a number of them around following the Christmas special the previous year, so may not be on the obvious one. where did you find the archive?

Comment: [A Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_tie-in_websites#Harold_Saxon) linked to the address (now containing some other site), which I then pasted into [the Internet Archive](http://archive.org/).

Comment: I'm guessing then it was on the http://www.votesaxon.co.uk/ page. But way back machine doesn't seem to want to work for it.